# Фильтр на Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs

Доброго времени суток!
Работаю на `ext js 4.2`.
Есть у меня `datefield`:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield', format: 'd.m.Y',   
    width: 300,
    margin: '0 50 0 150',
},{
    xtype: 'datefield', format: 'd.m.Y',
    margin: '0 0 0 100',  
    width:300
}
```

Грид:

```
var createGrid = function () {
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 1580,
    pagesize:'2',
    border: false,
    height: 500,
    defaults: {
        padding: '2'
    },
```

И `button`:

```
{
    xtype: 'button', text: 'Потвердить',

    width: 300,
    height: 25,
    margin:'0 0 0 120',
}
```

Нужно: выбрать дату и кликнуть на кнопку, а грид должен показать соответствующую запись.

Comment: ТЗ ясно, разрешите приступать?

Comment: @Other моете помочь?

Comment: Помочь - да, написать за Вас - за денежку :)

Comment: @Other Просто подскажите как?

Comment: IDE, руки, мозг. Вот как-то так.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42970/discussion-between-other-and-propro17).

Comment: Кто нибудь помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: @Other приступай

Comment: Денежку в кассу - приступлю.